# Authorizing an app engine version for firebase applications

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, firebase-authentication

I have an app engine / firebase project which I am deploying test versions of:

Base: MYAPPNAME.nw.r.appspot.com

Test Version: 28-dot-MYAPPNAME.nw.r.appspot.com

I can include the Base domain in Firebase authentication as an authorized domain but can not add the Test Version domain. The Firebase console just says 'A valid domain name is required (e.g. 'myapp.com').' I can add any random made up domain. What needs to change so that I can use Firebase Authentication in the test version?

Answer (score 0):

You may define multiple projects in your app, in your case a base one and a test one. Related detail is to be found on the [Configure multiple projects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects) documentation page.